# Child theme de WordPress no se muestra como el parent theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, theme

He realizado un child theme, creando los archivos stlye.css y functions.php. Mi theme tiene múltiples ficheros *.css y *.php. La cuestión es que no consigo que la web se muestre como el parent theme. Faltan elementos (principalmente en el Homepage). Me gustaría conocer la razón de esto. Describo a continuación los pasos que realizado hasta ahora:

1. He creado el fichero style.css con los requerimientos necesarios (campo "Template"= nombre del parent theme y demás).
2. En el fichero functions.php he incluido el siguiente código: (ver código al final de este escrito).
3. He intentado localizar de qué ficheros vienen algunos elementos de la web que no aparecen en el child theme (en el homepage de la web). Indico a continuación algunos ejemplos:

   - Por ejemplo, el ="widget-wrap" que se encuentra en el siguiente fichero localizado en la siguiente ruta del parent theme: MusicTheme\widgets\class-tmpl-image-gallery.php, no se encuentra en el child-theme.
   - Otro ejemplo: un texto que encabeza una sección dentro dentro del homepage de la web: "New Release Album" y se encuentra dentro del  anterior. Este texto está ubicado el el siguiente fichero: MusicTheme\functions\auto_install\import-widgets.wie
   - El siguiente texto: "This is an example of an event. You could add your" localizado en la ruta: MusicTheme\functions\auto_install\music-dummy-data.xml
4. Realizando pruebas, he optado por copiar todos los archivos (php y css) del parent theme al child-theme y parte de la información que no se mostraba, ya aparece en el child theme. No obstante, a pesar de esto, alguna información sigue sin mostrarse, como por ejemplo la del primer apartado anterior.
5. A modo informativo, en el apartado de "Settings>Reading" (del escritorio de Wordpress) el homepage está definido como: "A static page", con las opciones: "Homepage: Home" y "Post page: Blog".

**Cuestiones:**

1. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de proceder para que me aparezca la misma web que si estuviera activado el parent theme?
2. ¿Es buena práctica copiar todos los ficheros php/css del parent theme e incluirlos en el child-theme?

**Código incluido en el fichero functions.php (child theme):**

```
<?php
function wpshout_enqueue_MusicTheme_stylesheet () {

$parent_style = 'main-music-style';
$bs_style = 'bootstrap-min-style';
$font_style = 'fontawesomecss';
$tmpl_style = 'tmpl-music-style';
$comp_style = 'component-style';
$rtlbs_style = 'tmpl-rtl-bootstrap-style';
$rtlst_style = 'tmpl-rtl-style';
$cust_style = 'tmpl-customizer-css';    
$colors_style = 'colors';
$ie_sytle = 'ie';

$child_style  = 'main-music-style-child-style';
$child_bs_style = 'bootstrap-min-child-style';
$child_font_style = 'fontawesomecss-child';
$child_tmpl_style = 'tmpl-music-child-style';
$child_comp_style = 'component-child-style';
$child_rtlbs_style = 'tmpl-rtl-bootstrap-child-style';
$child_rtlst_style = 'tmpl-rtl-child-style';
$child_cust_style = 'tmpl-customizer-child-css';
$child_colors_style = 'colors-child';
$child_ie_style = 'ie-child';


wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $bs_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $font_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . 
'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $tmpl_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/theme-style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $comp_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/component.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $rtlbs_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/rtl-bootstrap.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $rtlst_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/rtl.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $cust_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin_style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $colors_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/colors.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $ie_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css' );         


wp_enqueue_style( $child_style,
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
            );

wp_enqueue_style( $child_bs_style,
            get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            array( $bs_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
            ); 

wp_enqueue_style( $child_font_style,
            get_stylesheet_directory() . 
'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css',
array( $font_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
); 

wp_enqueue_style( $child_tmpl_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/theme-style.css',
array( $tmpl_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);


wp_enqueue_style( $child_comp_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/component.css',
array( $comp_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

wp_enqueue_style( $child_rtlbs_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/rtl-bootstrap.css',
array( $rtlbs_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

wp_enqueue_style( $child_rtlst_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/rtl.css',
array( $rtlst_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

wp_enqueue_style( $child_cust_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/admin_style.css',
array( $cust_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

wp_enqueue_style( $child_colors_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/colors.css',
array( $colors_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

wp_enqueue_style( $child_ie_style,
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/ie.css',
array( $ie_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('1.1.2')
);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'wpshout_enqueue_MusicTheme_stylesheet' );
```

Comment: Hola fernanf, te damos la bienvenida al sitio y te felicito porque ésta es una pregunta interesante. No sé mucho de Wordpress, pero espero que alguien te pueda ayudar. Mientras esperas, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para aprender más sobre cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla). Un saludo y buena suerte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta copiar los archivos del parent theme al child theme. Wordpress toma automatáticamente lo que necesita del parent theme.

Como consecuencia de lo anterior lo que si o sí necesitás es que estén los dos themes instalados, el child y el parent.

Cuando el theme que usas como parent tiene configuraciones personalizadas y activas el child theme, como en la práctica estás cambiando de theme, estas personalizaciones se pierden (widget, colores, página de inicio) y hace falta cargarlas de nuevo.

El function que ponés se ve correcto por lo que supongo que debe venir por esto último tu problema.

Si no estás seguro de dónde está el problema te recomendaría primero crear un child theme limpio con el Child Theme Configurator y a partir de este personalizar. Para más data te recomiendo la segunda parte de este artículo (Crear un tema hijo de forma automática): https://gonzalonavarro.es/blog/crear-un-child-theme-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

No olvides copiar el archivo index.php en la carpeta del tema hijo (en todos los tutoriales que ví, lo pasan por alto). A mi me aparecía el tema twentyseventeen a pesar que el tema padre era shapely ¿?, lo cual implicaba que ningún cambio en el css se iba a ver. espero te sirva.